# What is the unsecure and fast counterpart of scp command?

Tags: command-line, files, file-transfer

I am looking for any command which is faster than scp to transfer files, security is not a concern here.

Comment: see man `rsync`

Comment: The unsecure counterpart is `rcp` (if not just a link to `scp` nowadays), but it depends on whether it is faster. Is encryption is the bottleneck (unlikely) or network speed (did you use `scp -C`)?

Comment: if you `scp` many files, try `rsync`, if it is a big file, it is not certain `rcp` will be faster.

Comment: @Philippos When `ssh` first came around, `rsh` was _much_ faster (on the old Sun SPARCstations that we were using). Likewise for the `*cp` variants. I haven't really used `rcp` since the 90's though, so I don't know what the current state of affairs is. I don't even _have_ `rsh`/`rcp` on my current system any longer.

Comment: Interestingly, [McKusick writes about `rsh`](http://www.oreilly.com/openbook/opensources/book/kirkmck.html) as a "temporary" tool that was supposed to be replaced in later versions of BSD. In talks, he has also mentioned `rsh` as a "mistake" :-)

Comment: @Kusalananda In those days (I only switched to Sun with an UltraSparc II) the crypto was done in software, so encryption was the bottleneck. Nowadays crypto hardware is becoming standard even in few-dollar ARM chips, that's why I'm pretty sure that network speed is the bottleneck. Network bandwidth grew by a factor of 10 to 100, encryption speed by several 1000. And yes, most networking was based on unsecure "mistakes" in those days, but with not so much evil out there it still worked.

Comment: @Philippos Thanks for the added info. Interesting. Yes. network speed (or unnecessary compression) may be the bottleneck for the OP.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227951/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-send-massive-amounts-of-data-between-two-computers