# How to pipe an input into the cat command

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, cat

I was reading an answer regarding sending large files from one Linux system to another by quick methods, and I was trying [this solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48555/495380)
The answer is saying that if you don't want to use the `tar` command, you can use the `cat` command instead [Like if you for example already have a tar file and you don't want to create another one, you can use the `cat` command instead directly]

So I have this command that I want to execute:

```
sam@sam:~/Documents$ cat test.mp4 | mbuffer -s 1K -m 512 | ssh 192.168.1.33 "cat > ~/Documents/here/test.mp4"
```

What I am trying to do using the above command is to send a large file (`test.mp4`) from the **Linux machine (A)** to the **Linux machine (B)**. The file (`test.mp4`) is available on the **Linux machine (A)** at `~/Documents`, what I want to do is to send this file from **the Linux machine (A)** to the **Linux machine (B)** on `~/Documents/here`

However, running the above command does not send the file, but instead, the Linux machine (B) is creating a plain-text file called test.mp4.

So the problem is that the cat command needs a way to read the input from the previous command, Got it :D?

[Edit]: After running the command above, I always get the following warning message

`mbuffer: fatal: Number of blocks must be at least 5.`

Comment: If your goal is to redirect standard input to a file, you could use the `tee` command instead of cat. But cat reads standard input by default if you have not given it anything, so your command should work

Comment: `cat` does read from standard input, and `ssh` does connect its stdin to that of the remote command, so yeah, the pipeline does work. What's wrong there is with the options to `mbuffer`, `-s 1K -m 512` asks for 1 kB blocks for a total buffer of 512 bytes, which obviously doesn't work. You probably want `-m 512k`, or `-m 512M`, depending on what size buffer you'd like, though a block size of 1 kB also seems quite small. Of course you could also do without `mbuffer`.

Comment: @Nephanth, now I tried the tee command the following way: `sam@sam:~/Documents$ cat test.mp4 | mbuffer -s 1K -m 512 | ssh 192.168.1.33 "tee > ~/Documents/here/test.mp4"` but it didn't make any change

Comment: `cat` reads stdin by default. You can give it the filename arg `-` to represent stdin, but it makes no difference. How big is the output `test.mp4`, and what does the start of the plain-text look like? I suspect `mbuffer` is failing (or not even installed), so ssh has nothing to pass to `cat`. Maybe try `mbuffer` on a smaller local file without using the remote system yet.

Comment: the mp4 file is 17 GigaByte size

Comment: @Nephanth, not much use for `tee` there if the data is going to just one place (it's called `tee` since it acts like a T-shape connection). Doing something like `tee filename > /dev/null` would work, but the writes to stdout would be useless...

Comment: I tried to omit the mbuffer part from the command and it worked, now what would be the suitable way to inject the mbuffer tool?

Comment: @Normal, are you sure you're not getting any errors from `mbuffer`...?

Comment: @ilkkachu, sorry for that, it wasn't included in my question, yes I was getting the following error the whole time "mbuffer: fatal: Number of blocks must be at least 5.
"

Comment: @Normal, well, given how a pipeline `foo | bar | blah` works so that the output of `foo` goes to the input of `bar`, and the output of `bar` goes to the input of `blah`, it seems rather reasonable that if `bar` fails due do invalid options, the whole thing breaks down.

Comment: OK, thank yous, now I'm figuring out what would be the correct parameters of the buffer

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using mbuffer?

Comment: I don't know wnat mbuffer does, but why are you not using `scp`?

Comment: @Bravo, I don't know, I'm trying the solution provided in [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/48555/495380), new to me

Comment: @glennjackman, because it's slow, I've tried FTP, SCP, SFTP. [There was also an option to do it through HTTP](https://askubuntu.com/a/1089904/1458818), but I didn't try it though, thought it would be much slower. So I thought I could manipulate something related to buffer or some nitty-gritty stuff. Because it _seems like_ the default transfer speed on LAN is 2MBps (over WI-FI and on Linux Mint 20 --> Linux Mint 20)

Comment: `provided in the answer` read the comments, and you'll see that the answer you copied verbatim causes errors :p